# How to check for Auto Start status of app in xiaomi in android

Tags: android, permissions, autostart

I need to check the status of Auto Start in permission setting of Xiaomi phone,
I got solution to open that setting but I am not getting how to check that my app status is on/off in permission for Auto Start.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you get any solution? We face similar issue. For now, we are prompting user to add the app in auto-start. But if we can programmatically get to do that, it would be great.

Comment: Have you find any solution to check our app is allowed or denied for auto start?

Comment: Yes, I got the solution of it but it is worked upto Android 7.0 version as 8.0 and above have restricted background services and some of are deprecated now. What I have done is I have checked the status of "Auto start" in setting and if it detects false I have shown a dialog which will lead user to the app setting and suggest him/her to check that auto start status. This is the only thing I found